# React Redux for opening multiple instance of application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, redux-form

I am working on creating ui for extension using react for a software called SketchUp in which when i'm opening a single instance of SketchUp then it's working but when I'm opening multiple instances of SketchUp and also that extension inside SketchUp then it's not working and throwing some error-"uncaught(in promise)". I am using react with redux.

Answer (score 0):

We are using react and redux on a sketchup extension without trouble even with several page.
please share code